# Integral of Inverse Trig Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm having trouble solving the following integral:

$\mathcal{I} = \int ds \frac{s^3}{arcsin(as)} $

With $a$ a numerical constant.

Giving it to Wolfram, it spits a solution in terms of a sum of $Si$ functions, which is not very useful to my goal.

To give more context:
$s$ is actually a function in my case, $s(x)$, and the integral runs from $s^2 (0) = 1$ to $s^2 (x)$, but i can work the functional form out myself, i just need some tips on how to integrate it like $s$ is a usual variable

Comment: Why do you think this integral has a closed form solution? As a rule of thumb, even though there are exceptions, if Wolfram Alpha can't find it, then more often than not there is no closed form solution.

Comment: I don't know if there is a closed form, i'm just hoping to find it. I saw that is not uncommon for Wolfram to having problems evaluating hard integrals

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment, but I wanted to quickly demonstrate why this likely does not have a closed form solution. The obvious substitution $s = \sin(x)$ (and I am putting $a = 1$ for simplicity, but it really doesn't matter) gives
$$\mathcal{I} = \int \frac{\sin^3(x)\cos(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Now this already looks suspicious, but if you use $\sin^3(x)\cos(x) = \frac{1}{8} (-\sin(4x) + 2\sin(2x))$, you get
$$\mathcal{I} = -\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{\sin(4x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{4}\int \frac{\sin(2x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{8}\mathrm{Si}(4x) + \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{Si}(2x),$$
where the $\mathrm{Si}$-function is known to not have an elementary representation. Hence unless there is a strange identity involving $\mathrm{Si}$-functions that noone knows about, there can't be a closed form solution to your integral.

Comment: Thank you for the help